# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_img.rows * _img.cols == vecSize)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cascade, assertion

I keep getting this error

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_img.rows * _img.cols == vecSize) in get, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/apps/traincascade/imagestorage.cpp, line 157
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/apps/traincascade/imagestorage.cpp:157: error: (-215) _img.rows * _img.cols == vecSize in function get
Aborted (core dumped)`

when running `opencv_traincascade`.  I run with these arguments: `opencv_traincascade -data data -vec positives.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 1600 -numNeg 800 -numStages 10 -w 20 -h 20`.

---

My project build is as follows: 
`workspace
|__bg.txt
|__data/ # where I plan to put cascade
|__info/
      |__ # all samples
      |__info.lst
|__jersey5050.jpg
|__neg/
   |__ # neg images
|__opencv/
|__positives.vec`

---

before I ran `opencv_createsamples -img jersey5050.jpg -bg bg.txt -info info/info.lst -maxxangle 0.5 - maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 1800`

---

Not quite sure why I'm getting this error.  The images are all converted to greyscale as well.  The neg's are sized at 100x100 and `jersey5050.jpg` is sized at 50x50.  I saw someone had a the same error on the OpenCV forums and someone suggested deleting the backup .xml files that are created b OpenCV in case the training is "interrupted".  I deleted those and nothing.  Please help! I'm using python 3 on mac.  I'm also running these commands on an ubuntu server from digitalocean with 2GB of ram but I don't think that's part of the problem.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention, after the `opencv_createsamples` command, i then ran `opencv_createsamples -info info/info.lst -num 1800 -w 20 -h20 -vec positives.vec`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it haha.  Even though I specified in the command the width and height to be 20x20, it changed it to 20x24.  So the `opencv_traincascade` command was throwing an error.  Once I changed the width and height arguments in the `opencv_traincascade` command it worked.

Comment: How did you figure out that the width and/or height were being changed after specifying them in the `opencv_traincascade` command?

Comment: I am facing same issue...can you please let us know how you figured the size of image ?

Comment: I figuresd it...once opencv_createsamples is called...read the output text. all the details are contained in the same.

Answer (score 0):

This error is observed when the parameters passed is not matching with the vec file generated, as rightly put by the terminal in this line

> Assertion failed (_img.rows * _img.cols == vecSize)

opencv_createsamples displays the parameters passed to it for training. Please verify of the parameters used for creating samples are the same that you passed. I have attached the terminal log for reference.

```
mayank@mayank-Aspire-A515-51G:~/programs/opencv/CSS/homework/HAAR_classifier/dataset$ opencv_createsamples -info pos.txt -num 235 -w 40 -h 40 -vec positives_test.vec
    Info file name: pos.txt
    Img file name: (NULL)
    Vec file name: positives_test.vec
    BG  file name: (NULL)
    Num: 235
    BG color: 0
    BG threshold: 80
    Invert: FALSE
    Max intensity deviation: 40
    Max x angle: 1.1
    Max y angle: 1.1
    Max z angle: 0.5
    Show samples: FALSE
    Width: 40                            <--- confirm 
    Height: 40                           <--- confirm
    Max Scale: -1
    RNG Seed: 12345
    Create training samples from images collection...
    Done. Created 235 samples
```